# Ambiguous FunctionOverloading in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a class A and it has two method foo which are actually overloaded. The class somewhat look like this

```
class A
{
public:
    bool foo(int& a);
    bool foo(size_t& a);
};

bool A::foo(int& a)
{
    return true;
}

bool A::foo(size_t& a)
{
    int new_a = a;
    return foo(new_a);  // here Cl throws me warning C4717: 'hweudm::UDMAbstractBaseEntity::SetAttribute' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
}

int main()
{
    A aObj;
    size_t val = 12;
    aObj.foo(val);
    return 0;
}
```

From the code it does not look ambiguous. But I don't want to this warning during compilation. So can Anyone tell me

1. Why I am getting this warning even though I have type casted size_t to int ?
2. whether this will be be an error not a warning on GCC.

Comment: That code won't compile; please show your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code isn't correct. The result of the conversion-cast `(int)a` is an rvalue, and it cannot bind to either lvalue reference.

The only thing that would come close, if it weren't horribly undefined behaviour, would be something like `foo(reinterpret_cast<int &>(a))`, but don't do this, since it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

isn't `size_t`:

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

? then A::foo(int& a) and A::foo(size_t& a) are exactly the same thing

Comment: No it isn't. `size_t` is an unsigned type, since size cannot be negative.

Comment: No and no! 1. `size_t` is "an alias of _one of the fundamental unsigned integer types_", not necessarily `unsigned int` (could be e.g. `unsigned long`). 2. Even on an implementation where it is defined as your typedef, `int&` (i.e. `signed int&`) and `unsigned int&` are _not_ the same thing at all, they are 2 different, incompatible types.

Comment: And size_t is also likely to be 64 bit (i.e. unsigned long long) when compiled for 64 bit.